# Updating source of video tag with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, django, ajax, video

I have an html page where there is a calendar, a video tag and a button. When a user clicks on a button, based on the timestamp the path of the video file from Django is sent and is received by an ajax call. When the page is opened for the first time or is refreshed and the date and time is selected and then the button is pressed the video corresponding to that date and time gets displayed on the page and can be played.

However when I change the date and time, the same video file which was opened previously gets displayed on the page, however the path of the video file which is being returned from the django is according to the new date and time.

HTML code

```
<div style="margin-left: 10%">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="recorded" name="btn_submit" value="Play Recorded Videos" onclick="record()" >Play Recorded Videos</button>

</div>



<div id="videoDiv" class="container" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 1%; align-items: center; display: none ">
    <video id='storedVideoId' width='100%' controls >
    </video>
    <br><br>
</div>
```

Javascript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        var dateNow = new Date();
             dateNow.setDate(dateNow.getDate());

             var timer

            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ defaultDate:dateNow  });

            });


            function getDataFromServer() {
                getVideoFile()
            }

            function getSelectedDate() {
                var from_date = $("#datetimepicker1").data("date")

                return {'from_date':from_date}          
            }

            function getVideoFile(){

                selectedDate = getSelectedDate()

                   $.ajax({
                    url: "/video/getVideoFile/",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data : {"from_date":selectedDate.from_date},

                    success: function(result){

                        if (result.result === "SUCCESS") {
                              var res =  result.videoFilePath;
                            source =  document.createElement('source');
                            source.setAttribute('src', res);
                            source.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4')
                            $('#storedVideoId').html(source)

                            $('#videoDiv').show()
                        } else {
                            $('#videoDiv').hide()
                            $('#videoDiv').empty()
                        }


                    }
                });
            } 

   </script>
```

The below javascript function I am using changes the text and attributes, so when a user wants to play a video, the text on the button should be Play Recorded Videos and when stop it the text should be Stop Recorded Videos as well as it hides the div.

```
<script>
    function record(){

        var recorded = document.getElementById("recorded").getAttribute('value');
        var text;

        if (recorded === "Play Recorded Videos"){

            getDataFromServer();
            text = document.getElementById("recorded").innerHTML = "Stop Recorded Videos";
            document.getElementById("recorded").setAttribute('value',"Stop Recorded Videos");
                } 
        else if (recorded === "Stop Recorded Videos") {

            $('#videoDiv').hide();

            document.getElementById("recorded").innerHTML = "Play Recorded Videos";
            document.getElementById("recorded").setAttribute('value',"Play Recorded Videos");
        }

        else {
            getDataFromServer();
        }


        }
</script>
```

However no error message comes, only the video file which was first displayed when the page was refreshed or loaded is displayed even after changing the date and time which corresponds to the video file name.

Answer (score 0):

Untested but you can try this setup in `success: function(result)` section:

```
success: function(result)
{

    if (result.result === "SUCCESS") 
    {
        var res =  result.videoFilePath;
        alert("NEW video path : " + res); //should be a valid path eg: https://example.com/myvideo.mp4

        source =  document.getElementById('storedVideoId');
        source.setAttribute('src', res);
        source.setAttribute('type', 'video/mp4')

        source.play(); //test playback of new video

        $('#videoDiv').show()
    } 
    else 
    {
        $('#videoDiv').hide(); $('#videoDiv').empty();
    }

}
```

Comment: Give me some feedback. Also make sure `res` is a path (string) that can be pasted in browser's address bar to view same video file in a new tab.

Comment: **edit** : Meant to say use `getElementById` , instead of your current `createElement` method. I need feedback about whether `getElement` (and updating its `src` value) works better than using `createElement`...

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested but no video file was displayed, however by the alert I got on screen I am sure the correct path is coming. I am not sure but is it because the video is not getting unloaded properly?